# Programming with Cython - General types for ndarray with shared code

Tags: python, numpy, templates, cython

I'm trying to write code which involves Numpy `ndarray`s, but they could potentially be of different types. The issue I'm having is, I don't know how to make Cython fast while making it handle all input-output type combinations as well. Here's an MWE for what I'm trying to achieve (of course, this doesn't compile, but it's representative of what I'd like to achieve):

`general_types.pyx`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython cimport integral
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from numpy cimport uint64_t

cdef extern from "<cstring>" namespace "std":
    void* memcpy (void* destination, const void* source, size_t num)

def cywhere(np.ndarray a not None, np.ndarray b not None):
    a = np.asarray(a, order='C')
    b = np.asarray(b, order='C')

    a_ind, b_ind = cywhere_wrapped[cython.typeof(a), cython.typeof(b)](a, b)

    a_ind = a_ind.astype(np.min_scalar_type(a.shape[0]))
    b_ind = b_ind.astype(np.min_scalar_type(b.shape[0]))

    return a_ind, b_ind

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef cywhere_wrapped(np.ndarray[integral] a, np.ndarray[integral] b):
    cdef vector[integral] a_ind = vector[integral]()
    cdef vector[integral] b_ind = vector[integral]()
    cdef uint64_t na = a.shape[0], nb = b.shape[0]

    return vector_to_np(a_ind), vector_to_np(b_ind)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef vector_to_np(vector[integral]& vec):
    cdef np.ndarray[integral] arr = np.empty(vec.size(), dtype=integral)

    cdef void* arr_p = <void*> arr.data
    cdef void* vec_p = <void*> &vec[0]

    memcpy(arr_p, vec_p, sizeof(integral) * vec.size())

    return arr
```

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

cython_extensions = [
    Extension('*', ['**/*.pyx'], language='c++', extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'])
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(cython_extensions, annotate=True),
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
)
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to handle any input/output types without converting the type of the array before passing it to `cywhere`. `a` and `b` can be any integer type (different from each other), and the outputs `a_ind` and `b_ind` can be other, completely different integer types as well. There are a couple of hurdles to this:

- Automatically select correct overload for `cywhere_wrapped`.
- Get correct type for both outputs with respect to `np.min_scalar_type(a.shape[0])`, to avoid allocating extra memory.
- Automatically select correct overload for `vector_to_np`
- `sizeof(integral)` should evaluate correctly

Is there a way to achieve this with one codebase? I'm willing to go down to C++ if that makes it simpler.

Edit: Compilation errors:

```
general_types.pyx:15:34: Can only index fused functions with types
general_types.pyx:29:24: Cannot coerce to a type that is not specialized
general_types.pyx:29:45: Cannot coerce to a type that is not specialized
general_types.pyx:34:44: Cannot coerce to a type that is not specialized
general_types.pyx:37:31: Type is not specialized
general_types.pyx:41:11: Type is not specialized
general_types.pyx:15:19: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
general_types.pyx:34:9: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
general_types.pyx:36:31: Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized
```

Comment: Could you show how it fails to compile? My feeling is that using typed memoryviews instead of `ndarray` might work (but this is without testing it...)

Comment: @DavidW Trying a typed memory view doesn't work, unfortunately. I added the compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difficulty here is that your using two types of type:

1. the numpy `dtype`, which is a runtime determined Python object, and
2. the type as specified by the Cython fused type, which is a compile time determined C type.

It isn't particularly easy to convert between these two types (it makes sense that could can't convert "dtype->fused type" since this would be using information at runtime to generate something needed at compile time) but it doesn't make sense that you can't convert the other way. To get round this issue I've used dummy arguments - arguments which aren't used but force Cython to generate code for a particular type.

The second problem is that you want your `a` and `b` array to be different types (I originally misread your comment and thought that you wanted the same type...). For this you just have to [duplicate the fused type declaration](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#fused-types-and-arrays) (see the note on the changes made with Cython >0.20.x). This also means you have to refine `integral` yourself - I added `int8_t` to it too. One consequence is that this ends up defining `4*4*4*4` versions of each function, which takes a while to compile, gives you a large module, and gives you `4*4*4*4` copies of each error message if you get something wrong

I made the following changes:

1. Switched from numpy arrays to typed memoryviews - I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that numpy arrays work with fused types
2. created two new fused types `uint_size_1/2`. Unlike the builtin `integral` this contains *unsigned* integers (which make sense for indices), and also 8 bit integers (which make sense for space saving). This will be used to represent the type of the output.
3. Made an internal function (`cywhere_internal`) accepting dummy arguments. This is an array argument (using a non-array argument doesn't work, for reasons that aren't 100% clear to me). The idea is that we work out which `dtype` is needed to store the indices, use that `dtype` to create an (empty) array, then pass that array to `cywhere_internal` to select the correct version of the function. `cywhere_internal` *must* be `def` rather than `cdef` because the selection is made at runtime.
4. Added a dummy `uint_size` argument to `vector_to_np`. This is a bit of a hack, but without the dummy argument Cython doesn't seem to interpret it as a fused type function. The argument is ignored.
5. Removed most of the `cython.boundscheck(False)` and `cython.wrapround(False)` decorators. You're not doing anything where these matter, so I think it's neater to leave them out.
6. I pass the `dtype` arguments through to all levels, since we need it in the `vector_to_np` function.
7. A few other smallish changes...

Code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libc.stdint cimport (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint64_t,
                          int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t)

ctypedef fused uint_size_a:
    uint8_t
    uint16_t
    uint32_t
    uint64_t
ctypedef fused uint_size_b:
    uint8_t
    uint16_t
    uint32_t
    uint64_t

ctypedef fused integral_a:
    int8_t
    int16_t
    int32_t
    int64_t
ctypedef fused integral_b:
    int8_t
    int16_t
    int32_t
    int64_t

cdef extern from "<cstring>" namespace "std":
    void* memcpy (void* destination, const void* source, size_t num)

def cywhere(integral_a[::1] a not None, integral_b[::1] b not None):
    dtype_a = np.min_scalar_type(a.shape[0])
    dtype_b = np.min_scalar_type(b.shape[0])

    return cywhere_internal(np.zeros((0,),dtype=dtype_a),np.zeros((0,),dtype=dtype_b),
                            dtype_a,dtype_b,
                            a,b)

def cywhere_internal(uint_size_a[:] dummya, uint_size_b[:] dummyb, 
                     dtype_a, dtype_b,
                     integral_a[::1] a, integral_b[::1] b):
    cdef vector[uint_size_a] a_ind = vector[uint_size_a]()
    cdef vector[uint_size_b] b_ind = vector[uint_size_b]()
    cdef uint_size_a dummy2a = 0
    cdef uint_size_b dummy2b = 0

    a_ind_np = vector_to_np(dummy2a, dtype_a, a_ind)
    b_ind_np = vector_to_np(dummy2b, dtype_b, b_ind)
    return a_ind_np, b_ind_np

cdef vector_to_np(uint_size_a dummy, dtype, vector[uint_size_a]& vec):
    cdef uint_size_a[::1] arr = np.empty(vec.size(),dtype=dtype)

    cdef void *arr_p

    with cython.boundscheck(False):
        # we're fine doing this on a 0 length array
        arr_p = <void*> &arr[0]
    cdef void* vec_p = <void*> &vec[0]

    memcpy(arr_p, vec_p, sizeof(uint_size_a) * vec.size())

    return np.asarray(arr)
```

It's difficult to be certain this works right, since it always generates 0 length arrays.

I'm not completely convinced of the value of saving space by using the smallest index type - there's a small slowdown at runtime for picking the correct version of `cywhere_internal`. I would only chose to do this if I was really running out of space.

Comment: There are two things wrong with this (unfortunately), a. `a` and `b` Can't be of different types, b. I want to avoid `a_ind_np.astype(...)` entirely by allocating the right kind of `vector` in the first place. They are indices but I'd prefer they don't take more space then they have to. Or would you recommend against that?

Comment: "`a` and `b` can't be of different types" is easily fixed - set them both to be `np_promote_types(np.min_scalar_type(a_ind_np),np.min_scalar_type(b_ind_np)`. I think allocating the right vector type is probably tricky - I'll have a think about how to do it (but it may be a few days before I get time to really look at it). I don't see a huge value in saving space unless you know that you're running out.

Comment: This is some hacky, yet pretty awesome work. I'll accept this as the answer, but I'd really like if `a`, `b`, `a_ind`, `b_ind` can be different types. Thanks a lot. :-D

Comment: Final edit... `a` and `b` can be different types. This is generating 256 different functions so actually takes quite a while to compile (and also duplicates any error messages 256 times which makes it pretty hard to debug). I'm not convinced you should actually use this...